# MySQL - Need search result of maximum matching letters from a string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select, sql-like

Hi I am writing my own MySQL query where I need a result of records as follows.

**Word in a table** - ABC XYZ

**My string** - ABC XYZQWER

when I ran my query as below -

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE where `column` LIKE 'ABC XYZQWER%';
```

I am getting empty result. I am aware of the fact that MySQL LIKE matches the result of string.

I need a way to figure this out.

I I searched it using 'ABC X' - it is giving me a proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `LOCATE()`:

```
SELECT `column` 
FROM myTable
WHERE LOCATE(`column`, 'ABC XYZQWER') = 1;
```

As long as there is a value `ABC XYZ` in the column named `column`, the result of the query will be at least:

```
+---------+
| column  |
+---------+
| ABC XYZ |
+---------+
```

---

**Finding an inner match**

Finding a matching string like `'BC'`, which is inside the search string `'ABC XYZQWER'`, is possible by using the compare operator `>=`. So the WHERE clause will look like this:

```
WHERE LOCATE(`column`, 'ABC XYZQWER') >= 1;
```

Comment: This gives me empty result

Comment: @D3Systems I tested it and it works on mysql. Please check your data.

Comment: @D3Systems Found a mistake. `column` is a special word to mysql, so it must be quoted with '`'. Have another try.

Comment: I am using "column" just for an example :) ..there is different field in my table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE a WHERE 'ABC XYZQWER' LIKE CONCAT(a.column, '%');
```

Comment: This doesn't solved my problem. What I have in hand is a word - 'ABC XYZQWER' and I want the result from table as 'ABC XYZ'

Answer (score 1):

It is because you dont have a work which has QWER. You are actually searching for a word which is not present. So you are getting a zero result.

For eg:

Word : qwertyuiuioo
search String : qwerty

select * from table where word like qwerty% you will get the result.
% takes any number of characters after the letters you have given which is not matching any value in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of how one might use LIKE clause in SQL queries:

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE where column LIKE 'ABC%';// matches ABCD, ABC D but not DABC

SELECT * FROM myTABLE where column LIKE '%ABC%';// matches any string that contains ABC anywhere in the string eg. DABC, D ABC but not D AB C

for your case you would do something like this:
SELECT * FROM myTABLE where column LIKE 'ABC XYZ%';
```

You won't be able to do perfect substring searches although you can apply Levenshtein distance searches as described here ([Levenshtein Distance MySQL Function](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552)). But do note these work a bit differently from LIKE clause in a way that it gives you the result based on the distance you specify for a search.

And after that you can use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE levenshtein("ABC XYZQWER",column) <= 4
```

This will give you the result set you are looking for; it will also give other words which fall under this range.

Comment: What I have in hand is a word - 'ABC XYZQWER' and I want the result from table as 'ABC XYZ'