# Compare to a substring of a variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I have a variable that is a string, and I want to select all columns that contain a subset of that string. What is the simplest way to do this?

For example, I have:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
value [IS A SUBSTRING OF] variable
```

So if my variable was something like 'ABCDEFG', I would like to find all values that are equal to
'A', 'AB', 'ABC', ... etc.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: where ... like '%search%'

Comment: @ThomasKrojer so in this case, it would be: value LIKE CONCAT('%', variable, '%')?

Comment: look for the `like` keyword. Think that is what you are serching for.

Comment: @jj72: Ronak Shah wrote a nice sample

Comment: @Thomas Krojer Won't this only find values where variable is a substring of value, but not the other way around?

Comment: @Thomas: it seems that he asked for the substring, not string contains variable.

Comment: @phuc: No, in this case he would use the substring function of mysql

Comment: @Thomas: I dont know whether he gave the wrong question or not. But he said `value [IS A SUBSTRING OF] variable`. and the `like` condition seems not to work in this case.

Comment: @Phuc: Okay, than he could use the instr() function, and check for return greater Zero ... select * from table where instr(value, variable) > 0

Comment: the same question.Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183303/mysql-need-search-result-of-maximum-matching-letters-from-a-string/27183913#27183913

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table 
where col1  like '%var%' or col2  like '%var%' or col3 like '%var%'
```

Comment: did you omit the single qoutes by intention?